# How to get element's attribute set in CSS class

Tags: javascript, css

I want to read the element's height and width.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .big {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px
    }
</style>

<div id="box1" style="width:50px; height=50px;"></div>
<div id="box2" class="big"></div>
```

For `box01` I can use `height=getElementById("box01").style.height` - that's fine.

But for box02 it doesn't work. It returns nothing.

Comment: what framework are you using? jquery / mootools / whatever?

Answer (score 2):

- [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) (for modern browsers)
- [currentStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for old IE versions)

Comment: T.J. Crowder: thanks for the edit, though I've noticed my typo almost immediately too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle()` to get the actual dimensions of any html element as follows:

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("box01");  
var height = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null).getPropertyValue("height");
```

See [getComputedStyle @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mootools you have to go with

```
 $('box2').getHeight().toInt();
```

just to have the int value (without the 'px')

otherwise in jquery

```
 $('.box2').height();
```

will do the trick

if you wanna go with the default javascript

```
 var elem1 = document.getElementById("box2");  
 var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
```

Comment: It's generally the convention here on SO that if you want an answer that uses a framework, you include a keyword for the framework on your question.  If you don't include any framework as a keyword, then you're asking for a plain javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look into [Jquery](http://jquery.com/). It's a very usefull piece of code.

[How to set CSS settings in Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#box1').css('height', 50);
```

To get a css property:

```
var box1Height = $('#box1').css('height');
```

The #box1 lets jquery know you want to do operations on the HTML object with the ID box1. That is what the # sign is for. More about that in [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

You would use `window.getComputedStyle` or `element.currentStyle` (depending upon which browser).  Older versions of IE require `currentStyle`.

Here's a quick interoperable shim that will make make a global function you can use in all browsers without including a whole library like jQuery:

```
//must be executed on or after the domready event, since it (may) require document.body to be non-null
var getComputedStyle = function() {
  var func = null;
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    func = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle;
  } else if (typeof(document.body.currentStyle) !== "undefined") {
    func = function(element, anything) {
      return element["currentStyle"];
    };
  }

  return function(element, style) {
    return func(element, null)[style];
  }
}();

//and use like so:
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("foo"), "display"); //might return "inline-block"
```

Code copied from this article: http://tmont.com/blargh/2010/4/get-computed-style-in-javascript.  There are many other similar ways to do this that can be found with a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the height of an element, it may be more to the point to read the clentHeight or offsetHeight property than the css.